# cross coupled nmos pair

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, coupling

For the given circuit, I am observing the source voltage of M1 and M2 as the min of the applied voltage. Here, the current is equal in both fets. But Vg is not the same. So, both cannot be in saturation. One of them may be in triode. Even if one is in triode, how is the source voltage of M1 and M2 equal the min of applied drain voltages?
[image]

Comment: What do you expect it to be?

Comment: @Finbarr, I can find it through math. But not able to visualize intuitively. So, needs some intuition

Comment: Well, what's the current through both MOSFETs? That should be easy enough to visualise.

Comment: @Finbarr Current is equal right?

Comment: They're in series and the gates don't take any significant current, so yes.

Comment: @Finbarr We equate currents and get the voltage. But how can we Intuitively say that the voltage is min of the given voltages.

Comment: I would suggest you redraw it so the MOSFETs are in line, it'll easier to see which ones, if any, should be conducting. The source voltage has to be somewhere between 14V and 10V as that's the only range available.